# How to copy cells from template.xml (2003 file) to mydoc.xltm

Tags: excel, vba

Need help with code to copy cells(range/whole sheet) from second workbook.

Macro is used inside 094-0.....macro.xlsm file and I need to copy first sheet (or range A1:T10 at least) from second file to last sheet from fist file. Then close the second file without saving changes.

I have problem with activation of wokrbook and paste data.

```
Dim wbk As Workbook

Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).name = artikl & "_SK" & i 'it's OK 

strSecondFile = "C:\…..\template_2003_XML.xml"
strFirstFile = "C:\…..\094-022605-00001_w_macro.xlsm"

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strSecondFile)

    Range("A1:T350").Copy

Set wbk = Workbooks("094-022605-00001_w_macro").Activate

With wbk.Sheets(sheets.Count)
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
End With

Workbooks("template_2003_XML.xml").Close savechanges:=False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to `.Activate` just set the workbook without it. • You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Also spcify in which workbook and worksheet this range is `Range("A1:T350")`. Note that you `Set wbk` twice to two different workbooks. So you should use two differen variables too, like `wbkSource` and `wbkDestination`.

Also your with statement `With wbk.Sheets(sheets.Count)` is useless unless you tell your range a starting `.` that it should use tha with statement: `.Range()`

```
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = artikl & "_SK" & i 'it's OK 

Dim SourceFilePath As String
SourceFilePath = "C:\…..\template_2003_XML.xml"

Dim DestinationFilePath As String
DestinationFilePath = "C:\…..\094-022605-00001_w_macro.xlsm"

Dim wbkSource As Workbook
Set wbkSource = Workbooks.Open(SourceFilePath)

Dim wbkDestination As Workbook
Set wbkDestination = ThisWorkbook 'Workbooks("094-022605-00001_w_macro")


wbkSource.Worksheets("source sheet").Range("A1:T350").Copy    
With wbkDestination.Sheets(sheets.Count)
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With

wbkSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.